# CakePHP 3: Add specific JS/CSS file to a specific view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP 3.3.10. I need to add a JavaScript file to a specific view.

```
// default.ctp  
// I need to remove this script in default.ctp and load only in a specific view.  

<?= $this->Html->script(['otherfile.js', 'otherfile.js', folder/scripts.js']) ?>
```

**How can I load the js file only in this view?:**

```
// index.ctp  
// I need to load the scripts.js file only in this view
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457293/cakephp-3-x-load-css-in-head-tag-for-a-specific-action

Comment: @ndm I've tried it but it's not loading correctly. I need to load it after all the scripts in default.ctp.

Comment: Then position the block accordingly, and/or create a new, custom one. And if you tried something, please show what you've tried and describe _what exactly_ the problem with it is. Also don't just do 5 minutes of trial & error, read the answer, read [**the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-javascript-files) (**[2](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.View.Helper.HtmlHelper.html#_script)**), then implement it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your index.ctp file and insert this code at the bottom.

**For JS**

```
echo $this->Html->script('/otherdir/scripts');
```

or

```
echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js');
```

Will output:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The first parameter can be an array to include multiple files.

```
echo $this->Html->script(['jquery', 'wysiwyg', 'scripts']);
```

Will output:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/wysiwyg.js"></script>
<script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

You can append the script tag to a specific block using the block option:

```
echo $this->Html->script('wysiwyg', ['block' => 'scriptBottom']);
```

Then, in your layout, make sure to have the said block so they get outputted:

```
<?= $this->fetch('scriptBottom')?>
```

**For CSS**

This method of CSS inclusion assumes that the CSS file specified resides inside the webroot/css directory if path doesn’t start with a ‘/’.

```
echo $this->Html->css('forms');
```

Will output:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/forms.css" />
```

The first parameter can be an array to include multiple files.

```
echo $this->Html->css(['forms', 'tables', 'menu']);
```

Will output:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/forms.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/tables.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/menu.css" />
```

Comment: In my case, output new line not work? like following 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/forms.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/tables.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/menu.css" />
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 10):

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('style.css',['block'=>true]); ?>
```

The block = true option causes the css to load inside the head tag. It will be loaded where you put the code `<?php echo $ this-> fetch ('css'); ?>` in your template

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->request->params['controller']` to get the current controller and `$this->request->params['action']` for controller action.

Example:

```
<?php 
  // default.ctp 
   echo $this->Html->script(['otherfile.js', 'otherfile.js']);
   if (in_array($this->request->params['action'], ['index'])){
    // your conditional script block
    echo $this->Html->script(['folder/scripts.js']);
  }

?>
```

Hope it should help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add below  code in your view :

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('/otherdir/scripts'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add css and js file on the top of view file:

`echo $this->Html->script(array('ajaxupload.3.5.js'));`

`echo $this->Html>css(array('new_layout.css'));`